# Jquery AutoComplete multidimensional data source

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

This is my data source in JSON format:

```
{
"list-1":
    [{"id":"1","value":"andy"},{"id":"2","value":"sandy"}],
"list-2":
    [{"id":"1","value":"candy"},{"id":"2","value":"brandy"}],
"list-3":
    [{"id":"1","value":"mandy"},{"id":"2","value":"dandy"}]
}
```

And I'm trying to get following output:

```
<div id="result">
    <ul class="list-1">
        <li>andy</li>
        <li>sandy</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list-2">
        <li>candy</li>
        <li>brandy</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list-3">
        <li>mandy</li>
        <li>dandy</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The default data source (JSON format) which works is as follow: [{"id":"1"},{"foo":"bar"}],  I haven't been able to find a good/easy to follow documentation/tutorials on how to retrieve multidimensional data arrays.

Can anyone please shed some light for me on this, what do I need to modify/override within JQuery AutoComplete plug-in to achieve this output (within Select or Success event? or  should I modify the rendering part and how)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is an example running code with customised output and default single dimension data http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FqEJt (Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/2746987/2518765)

Comment: I've found a workaround, edited the data source making it single dimensional and added `type` to each item, and then in renderItem function I check for the type, if the type is `list=1` I append the item to my custom UL with the ID `list-1`. While this works this is not exactly what I was after and I'll leave the question here in case if someone comes up with better idea. code in the next comment.

Comment: `jQuery("#toplivesearch").data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    var container;
    if(item.type == "list-1"){
     container = $("#list-1");
    }
    if(item.type == "list-2") {
     container = $("#list2");
    }
    if(item.type == "list-3") {
     container = $("#list-3");
    } 
 return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(container);
};`

You have to create your own UL's in the html
`<ul id="list-1"></ul><ul id="list-2"></ul>`and so on

At the end you'll end up with an extra empty UL which you can hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jquery tmplt as a templating tool https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl) for what you are trying to achieve. Since your data is a JSON object you could create a template:

html:

```
<div id="result">

</div>


//On document ready:
$(document).ready(function(){
//set your json object (this could be from a ajax call or whatever)    
var objectData = 
    {
    "list-1":
        [{"id":"1","value":"andy"},{"id":"2","value":"sandy"}],
    "list-2":
        [{"id":"1","value":"candy"},{"id":"2","value":"brandy"}],
    "list-3":
        [{"id":"1","value":"mandy"},{"id":"2","value":"dandy"}]
    }

    //init variables
    var key, count = 0;
    //loop through the object:
    for(key in objectData) {
       //create a UL element for each main item:
       $('#result').append('<ul class="' + key + '"></ul>');

        //loop through each child object:
        if(objectData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < objectData[key].length ; i++)
             //add the template:  
             $.tmpl( '<li>${value}</li>', { "value" : objectData[key][i].value }).appendTo("." + key);  
        }
}

});
```

For this be sure to include the tmpl.js CDN: http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eRQ4V/

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your code but since I'm trying to implement it within the existing AutoComplete structure it doesn't work, or I should say I haven't been able to implement it yet. as far as I have been able to dig, in order to achieve what I'm trying to do I have to override Response event and also __renderItem function of AutoComplete. I'll try to come up with a sample code of the whole thing to better explain the issue

Comment: You could potentially still use the logic to loop through your JSON object and then apply the Autocomplete logic instead of the template plugin I was using.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to do however data that travels between functions gets manipulated somehow, considering the sample data source in the question, renderMenu function passes the first array of data only to renderItem function 3 times, need to figure out what to do here (please see my comment on the question for sample running code)

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure, which autocompleter you mean, but I guess you mean this one: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete right?

I found that, most auto completion solutions are not really flexible at all. And it seems that there are only a few out there (although I think there were many some time ago). But there is one autoCompletion plugin used at [xing](https://www.xing.com) that is available on their github page, that should be flexible enough to possibly fit to your special markup their. It was designed to be flexible. Check it out [on github/xing/jquery.autocompletr](https://github.com/xing/jQuery.autocompletr).

The readme only mentions `source`, `inputProcessor` and `outputProcessors` parameters of that tool, but there also an `itemRenderer`, `containerRenderer` and `beforeShow` hook you can use. The `itemRenderer` and `containerRenderer` you most probably need, to get your special markup done.

Hopefully this helped. But your JSON response is really strange for usage in  an autocompleter, so it also might be that you have to either change your JSON response to only result in one array with data, or write your own for your usecase.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete is what I'm trying to use, problem is accepting defeat in getting AutoComplete to do what I want.. My JSON response is generated by PHP (I'm using YiiFramework) and I can manipulate it with no problem, current format just seemed simple to me. Thanks